# Is it acceptable for a derived function to not make use of all available parameters?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have an overridden member function that does not make use of all the parameters it is passed? Does this indicate a design flaw?

Comment: Please make a practical example because your question, as it is, is too broad.

Comment: I would say, "not necessarily, but worth investigating".

Comment: Not necessarily. I have an example in my code base: some "hints" for optimisers. Sometimes hints are not required.

Comment: It is always a good idea to watch for unused parms. The compiler typically will rise a warning. If your interface is too broad and pass more or less often unneeded parms, it can be seen as a design problem. But there is no *general* good/bad advice here.

Comment: @Jack: For me the question is quite clear and there is no need to get an example of an overriden function which did not take all parms. What should it help? Even if there is no yes/no answer for all general cases, all needed information is in the question.

Comment: @Klaus Thanks, If you reply as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to watch for unused parameters. Compilers typically will rise a warning and this is definitely meant as a hint to watch out for potential problems.

If your interface is too broad and pass more or less often unneeded parameters, it can be seen as a design problem. But there are tons of examples, where in some cases parameters are left unused.

On one hand, compilers rise a warning, on the other hand compilers provide attributes to suppress the warning like this example:

```
int f1( int x [[gnu::unused]] )
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why we did not see the `[[unused]]` attribute in the C++ standard is a bit a mystery to me.

There is simply no general good/bad advice here. Try to avoid it but make it not a academic rule. You always should think about an alternative, but also this can be more problematic.